# Отформатировать файл json одной командой (in-place)

Tags: linux, json, shell, форматирование

Как можно отформатировать файл json одной командой shell (in-place)?

Хочу команду вида

```sh
$ format-json --in-place MyFile.json
```

---

В [этом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/q/352098/9221336) есть много ответов как отформатировать файл json с записью результата в консоль или новый файл, то есть потребуется как минимум две команды (например так: `jq . MyFile.json >temp && mv temp MyFile.json`).

Comment: А какой в этом смысл?

Comment: @AlexeyTen 1) указывать имя файла два раза неудобно (особенно если оно длинное). 2) чем меньше команд (и чем меньше в них символов), тем лучше, потому что можно быстрее их набрать (в разумных пределах, конечно, но форматирование файла двумя командами не выглядит лаконичным)

Comment: Напишите скрипт (с)

Comment: или если хочешь сделать чтобы «было для всех» напиши авторам наиболее понравившейся/подходящей утилиты (`jq`) чтобы они добавили соответствующий ключик....

Comment: Не думаю что это доступно будет без сторонних утилит - https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/105

Comment: Возьмите юникс утилитку `jtc` - она как раз позволяет делать JSON изменения in-place, а по возможностям не уступает jq